# AWS S3 conditions and AWS lambda suffix/prefix

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

I would like to upload image files to AWS S3 bucket which triggers a Lambda function that modify the images, using python `boto3` library and presigned URLs.
And I would like to implement the following rules:

1. Use the Content-Type condition to restrict the files to be uploaded only to image files (e.g., jpeg and png)
2. Use the suffix or prefix so that Lambda function is activated only when image files are uploaded

Currently my codes and settings are as follows:
[Python codes]

```
boto3.client('s3', ...).generate_presigned_post(...,
  Key='userupload/' + key,
  Fields={
    "Content-Type": "image/jpeg",
  },
  Conditions=[
    ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", "image/"],
  ]
)
```

[Lambda settings]

- Prefix: userupload
- Suffix: .jpg

But, when I try to upload an jpeg file, the file is successfully uploaded to the expected S3 bucket (in `userupload` folder), while the Lambda function is not triggered.
I also found that the uploaded object doesn't have the standard "Type" value, while it has the following Metadata:

- Type: System defined
- Key: Content-Type
- Value: image/jpeg

Are there any good ways to obtain the expected behavior?
Thank you very much for your helps in advance!

Comment: I am unsure what the generate_presigned_post has to do with triggering the Lambda. Ot would be nice to know how the Lambda is created; in the console or through CDK (or other IaC). To answer your question I assume the Lambda function is created in the console in which case follow this guide https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html

Comment: `generate_presigned_post()` creates a presigned URL that can be used to upload a file to an S3 bucket, and the Lambda function is triggered when a file is uploaded to the bucket. I created the Lambda function by pushing a Docker image to Amazon ECR.

Comment: How did you setup the trigger? can really know it based on the questions. you would've setup trigger either at s3 or lambda

Answer (score 0):

For the lambda trigger you should considerer this:

1. In your presigned url you should configure as "post_object" (or put)
2. In your lambda trigger, the event must be put (for this case)
3. In your lambda trigger, the bucket must be the one which will receive the file